# Php get month number from string with date

Tags: php, string

i have a string in this format `'2015-4-28'`
How i get month number for this string ( the value in this example is 4)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to do this:

```
date('m', strtotime($date));
```

Change the m to an n to get the month without the leading 0.

Comment: this one is nice because it avoids having to know the location of the month in the datetime stamp.

Answer (score -2):

With this:

```
<?php
$a = "2015-4-28";
$parts= explode("-", $a);
echo $parts[0]; // 2015
echo $parts[1]; // 4
echo $parts[2]; // 28
?>
```